# What does "recounting your exploits of the night" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

The text says:

> Well, some of the other questions about, things like, "What do I do with myself in the waiting room." This is one of my favourite questions. Again, that's very insightful, because here are things not to do. In this cell phone culture in which young people seem to think that the world is their phone booth, a thing not to do is to be sitting there **recounting your exploits** of the night before in full...in full earshot of the receptionist, who may go back and report to her boss on what she just heard. And it's over for you.

It is an excerpt in a conversation about some tips on job interviews. What does **recounting your exploits** mean here?

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary for the meaning of 'recount' and 'exploit'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey ok, so it means not to boast about your achievement right? but what does it mean by "exploits of the night"

Comment: What might young people do at night that would be embarrassing for others to hear about, and affect their job chances if they boast of it audibly?

Comment: Bear in mind that it's not just the exploits that would affect their job chances, but the fact that they were imprudent enough to boast about them publicly. An indication of poor judgement skills.

Comment: Like the young men I heard on the bus the other day. They had all been out drinking and clubbing the night before, and they were discussing, among other things, the amount of alcohol (and drugs) they had consumed, the girls they had approached, or not approached, their opinions of girls' looks (not always complimentary or nicely expressed), a fight their pal had got into, various silly pranks they had carried out, and so on. They seemed not to care that everyone could hear them.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you!